# SharePoint 2013 REST API: Updating File Metadata

Tags: c#, json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to modify the metadata of a file that has just been uploaded.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = _authenticator.Credential }))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", _authenticator.Token);
    client.BaseAddress = _authenticator.Endpoint;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");

    string cmd = String.Format("_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Drop Off Library')/items({0})", file.Id);

    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file);
    StringContent test = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(cmd, test);
}
```

I successfully GET the file's metadata above, and store it in a SharePoint file model of my own creation. I modify one of the file's metadata fields, and then attempt to merge the deserialized object back in. This has been resulting in a 400 Bad Request error. Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to replace the lines:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file);
StringContent test = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

with

```
var test = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
test.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
```

since in your case the *invalid* `Content-Type` header is generated.

[image]

See [JSON Light support in REST SharePoint API released](https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) for a list of supported formats.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the lines to the ones you provided and it worked properly!